# Appfog mysql tunnel error - Encryption not available on this event-machine

Tags: mysql, ruby, tunnel, appfog, paas

We've established a connection to appfog using caldecott and `af tunnel` command. We try to connect to a mysql service to load and execute a big .sql file to populate the db.

We tried it from 3 different machines Ubuntu on VirtualBox, Feora 18 on VirtualBox and native Ubuntu. We also tried it on another account, but we keep getting this error:

```
Launching 'mysql --protocol=TCP --host=localhost --port=10000 --user=uZVQhGhbYEzyb --password=pNu1l6xbXVhbj d39d6d0e6344b41a4aaeada16dfca2a46'

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
 what():  Encryption not available on this event-machine
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0

Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: if it works with smaller payloads then the size of the payload is the issue.

Answer (score 11):

Thanks to appfog customer support I managed to solve this problem. My distro lacked an ssl provider.

To solve this on fedora

```
yum install openssl openssl-devel
gem uninstall eventmachine
gem install eventmachine
```

However I still had a problem with executing big sql scripts. Does anyone know a neat solution to this issue?

Comment: Thanks. In my case I had to install libssl-dev instead openssl-devel. (debian machine)

Comment: By "problem", do you mean that the connection is unstable? Because that has always been my experience with AppFog tunneling.

Comment: On Fedora, make sure to reinstall all of the gems after installing openssl and openssl-devel

Answer (score 3):

For a Windows system, I got it to run by doing the following:

1. Install Win32 OpenSSL v1.0.1e Light from [here](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html)
2. Install Visual C++ 2008 Redistributables from the same link if not already installed.
3. Re-install eventmachine in Ruby with the newly installed open-ssl.

> gem install eventmachine -- --with-ssl-dir=C:\OpenSSL-Win32

(you might need C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin)

After the installation is complete, you're ready to tunnel to any service! (In my case postgresql)

Comment: OpenSSL distribution from the provided link didn't work for me. `gem install eventmachine` command didn't show any error messages while building so I wasn't sure if it was built with ssl support as expected. But I was able to install an alternative OpenSSL distribution from sourcefourge (http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/openssl.htm), used it in the `with-ssl-dir` option and everything went just fine.